# Writing user script meta header via AJAX

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Is it possible to write a user script so that the header is written from a ajax request? I'm trying to make a simple web game that has a high score mode but do not want it to interrupt any background tabs that they are visiting on a site. (think webpage dynamic breakout for the game).

for example if the user has this mode enabled on the current page the header would have:

```
 // ==UserScript==
 // @include http://www.example.com/subpage/index.html
 // ==/UserScript==
```

if it was not on the page they enabled it on it it would not be there at all so it wont run.

Comment: Why are you writing a userscript when you are making a game website?

Comment: basically for a personal project im making a website and a plugin. The plugin contacts the server to save scores and pass specific rules. What happens is that the plugin  makes the current site select into a breakout/pong style game where div elements allow you to have blocks and obstacles. Its more of a learning experience than anything serious.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to put the game on your own website only, or via a userscript on all pages the user browses?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I admit i wrote that in a hurry. I want it to be able to use any page. However i want the url they selected (the include) to be able to only run on that page they are currently on. so if they have a page open on the same domain. It will not interrupt the users web browsing.

Comment: That's nothing userscript headers can do. You might however stop the game on pages in the background.